# Key authentication

Tags: package-management, software-installation, authentication

I bought *PC World* magazine which came with an installation disk for Ubuntu 16.04.

When I wanted to install applications from the store, there appeared a prompt for key authentication. What should I do?

Comment: Please write in English if you want to receive support here :)

Comment: Ok! Do you speak Polish? THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticate in the Software Center with the same user password that you use to login to Ubuntu. Or just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> if you haven't set a user password yet, but if you haven't got a user password you should set a strong user password to keep your operating system secure.

Comment: THX you. You are clever in ubuntu.

Comment: THX, but I don't know how add new question. HELP!!!

Comment: If you have a new question in Polish that you want to be translated into English, copy the original text into [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and provide a link to your pastebin text in a comment, and I'll try to translate it like I did the last time. When I've read it, I'll tell you whether or not it should be asked as a separate question.